# After assessment, what's the next for EOI in Australia?

Tags: visa, working-visas, australia

I want to apply for nomination of EOI to the Northern Territory. I have passed the APC exam for the pharmacy board.  I have the results, but I was searching for clear instructions on how to proceed. I could not find anything past this.
So how do I apply for the Northern Territory?

Comment: Have you searched on https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder?

Comment: For NT, I've only found two employer-sponsored visas, 187 or 482.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this information can prove to be useful to you.

https://www.asiapacificgroup.com/expression-of-interest-eoi

It is suggested you consult (and hire) a registered MARA agent for this. They'll be able to provide you with the best advice on how to go about the nomination of EOI to the Northern Territory.

Comment: I see that you state that you work for this company in your profile, but it would be better to reveal your connection here, in your answer. Answers should be general, not linked to a particular company or provider and use official websites/documents.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Please [edit] the essentials into your text.